# acf returns "'lag.max' must be at least 0" and arima returns "only implemented for univariate time series" despite properly structured timeseries data

Tags: r, time-series, arima, autoregressive-models

I have a dataframe that appears as follows:

```
  T1       T2       T3
1 4.693798 3.339923 1.960526
2 5.108974 4.041096 3.227176
3 4.323944 3.936614 3.755302
4 4.516129 3.859621 2.921308
5 4.210526 3.716563 3.601480
6 5.143293 4.007018 3.778689
```

I then convert it to a timeseries data structure and verify it is timeseries data and appears correct as follows:

```
propTS <- t(as.matrix(propDf[2:4]))
propTS <- as.ts(propTS)
is.ts(propTS)
time(propTS)
```

It outputs:

```
      [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]
1 4.693798 5.108974 4.323944 4.516129 4.210526 5.143293
2 3.339923 4.041096 3.936614 3.859621 3.716563 4.007018
3 1.960526 3.227176 3.755302 2.921308 3.601480 3.778689
```

Looks good to me. But when I execute the below acf function, I get the error, "Error in acf(propTS, na.action = na.pass) : 'lag.max' must be at least 0":

```
acf(propTS, na.action=na.pass)
```

Similarly, when I attempt to execute the below line, I get the following error, "Error in arima(propTS, order = c(1, 0, 0)) : only implemented for univariate time series":

```
AR <- arima(propTS, order = c(1,0,0))
```

I have checked online examples and my data structure appears to be like other time series data that people use as inputs for this function. I have attempted various other solutions for troubleshooting but have not encountered a solution thus far. Can anyone identify what may be wrong with my input and why it is interpreting it as *not* univariate? It appears univariate to me. I have a column for each individual and three timepoints for the data. Seems univariate.

Notably, this error persists even when generating a 10x50 matrix of random numbers and then proceeding through the same procedure as above by converting to a timeseries.

```
propTS<-matrix(rnorm(100),nrow=10,ncol=50)
```

Answer (score 1):

The error might ocurr when using transpose function t()
I´m not sure why are you doing that, but I think you have your own reasons.

```
propTS <- ts(as.matrix(df))
acf(propTS, na.action = na.pass)
```

The second error ocurrs because arima() only supports univariate time series, that is only one variable, in this case you have 3. You can do this (if this is what you want).

```
TS1 <- ts(df$T1)
TS2 <- ts(df$T2)
TS3 <- ts(df$T3)

arima(TS1, order = c(1,0,0))
arima(TS2, order = c(1,0,0))
arima(TS2, order = c(1,0,0))
```

The acf plots look like this:

[image: Acf plots]

Comment: Thanks Mariano. I transposed it as I wanted the subjects to be the columns and the timepoints to be the rows. I had previously thought it would be rows for subjects and columns for timepoints, but I noted that it output that my timepoints were 1 to 6 (my # of subjects), so I transposed.

Comment: Regarding the arima() function, I was originally under the assumption that it input a full timeseries matrix. This webpage (https://rpubs.com/JSHAH/481706) seens to make it seem that way. But it seems what you are saying is that it accepts a vector for the autoregressive model, rather than a matrix. If I wanted arima() executed for each series, I would need to do it iteratively via a for loop or apply or something. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Absolutely! A loop or apply might work! Also lapply() -> Like this: lapply(lapply(df, ts), arima, order = c(1,0,0))